# Glide is taking too much time to show image in recycler view grid item

Tags: android, image, android-glide

I am using glide to load images in Recycler view. Some images are loaded but some are not loading and some are taking too much time to load.

This is my glide code:

```
    Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext())
                        .load(Image_URL+listData.getImageurl())
                        .thumbnail(.5f)
                        .override(100,130)
                        .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                Log.e("pic_failed", "matches");
                                holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                if (sess_gender.equalsIgnoreCase("Male")){
                                    holder.imageurl.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.girl_default));
                                }
                                else{
                                    holder.imageurl.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.boy_default));
                                }
                                return false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                return false;
                            }
                        })
//                        .error(default_img)
                        .into(holder.imageurl);
```

Comment: Image size maybe bigger from `Image_URL+listData.getImageurl()`

Comment: the image size is 50-60 kb

Comment: all images are thumnails

Comment: If images are not heavy to load, the only remained guess is a poor internet connection.

Comment: internet connection is also good . the main issue is some image are load quicly and some image taking time (40 kb image ).